# Finite abelian section rank of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

I can't fully understand the definition of *finite abelian section rank* of a group.

By definition, a group $G$ has *finite abelian section rank* if it has no infinite elementary abelian $p$-sections for any prime $p$.

Can someone clarify what we mean by infinite elementary abelian $p$-sections?

Answer (score 2):

A section of a groups $G$ is a quotient group $M/N$, where $M$ and $N$ are subgroups of $G$, and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $M$. A group is an elementary abelian $p$-group if it is abelian of exponent $p$. Presumably this means that the group has no sections that are infinite elementary abelian $p$-groups.